# How can I  upgrade my device without going through my carrier?

Tags: updates, android-versions

Are there sites available that will allow me to upgrade to the latest version of Android without depending on my carrier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not officially, and not without voiding your warranty. You would need to install a custom ROM, of which there are several, the most popular of which seems to be CyanogenMod.

Comment: I would change the word "legally" to "officially."  There is nothing illegal about installing custom ROMs on your device.  To do so, however, you must root the device and unlock its bootloader, which most carriers and manufacturers do not support, and this may void the device's warranty.

Comment: Well, that's why it's in quotes. But I take your meaning and I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to download and install an awesome rom for your phone, you should read this: http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices

Comment: Thanks Friends, CyanogenMod seem to be most famous. Also things I learnt is HTC Android phones are most famous, and preferred. Only sad part is the Samsung Android model I have Galaxy S GT I9003 is not yet got ROM in that site :(